# Apex classs exposed as Rest API giving 404 error on call

Tags: apex, rest-api, exception

I am trying to test my Apex class code exposed as rest api. For this, I am making a call to this API using postman.
Below is the class I created

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SurboChat/SaveChatTranscript')
global with sharing class SurboChatIntegration {
    @HttpPost
    global static ResponseClass doPost(){
        SurboChatTranscript chatRequest;
        try{
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String reqBody = (req.requestBody.toString());
        System.debug(reqBody);
        chatRequest = (SurboChatTranscript)json.deserialize(reqBody, SurboChatTranscript.class);
        Account accountObj = new Account(id = chatRequest.AccountId);
        //List<Account> accountObj = [select fields[ALL] from Account where id =:chatRequest.accountId];
        Case caseObj = new Case(id = chatRequest.CaseId);
        //List <Case> caseObj = [select fields[ALL] from Case where id=:chatRequest.caseId];
        SurboChat__c surboChat = new SurboChat__c (ChatBody__c=chatRequest.body, CaseId__c = caseObj.Id, AccountId__c=accountObj.Id, StartTime__c = chatRequest.startTime, EndTime__c=chatRequest.endTime);
    
        insert surboChat;
        
        }
        
        catch(Exception e){
            Integration_Log__c log = new Integration_Log__c();
            log.Component_Name__c='SurboChat Transcript';
            log.Error_Message__c=e.getMessage();
            log.IsIntegration__c=true; 
            insert log; 
            if(log.Error_Message__c!=null)
            {
                ResponseClass sc = new ResponseClass();
                sc.status ='ERROR!';
                sc.message=log.Error_Message__c;
                return sc;
            }
            
        }
        ResponseClass sc = new ResponseClass();
        sc.status ='Success';
       // String query=[Select id from SurboChat__c where StartTime__c = :chatRequest.startTime AND EndTime__c = :chatRequest.endTime];
        sc.message = chatRequest.surboId;
        return sc;
       
    }


   public class SurboChatTranscript{
        String surboId;
        String body;
        String accountId ;
        String caseId;
        DateTime startTime;
        DateTime endTime;
        String status;
        String error;

    }
    
   global class ResponseClass{
        string status{get;set;}
        string message{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Below is the request I am making to call the above api

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<instance_name>/services/data/v53/SurboChat/SaveChatTranscript' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token_id>' \
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=MG4uOQDPEey3pZcptr2XgA; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1' \
--data-raw '{
    "surboId": "2333",
    "body": "This is the surbo chat transcript test we are doing to save it in Salesforce",
    "accountId": "null",
    "caseId": "null",
    "startTime": "2020-08-11:10:10:10",
    "endTime": "2020-08-11:11:10:10",
    "status": "null",
    "error": "null"
}'
```

With this call, I am getting errors:

> [
> {
> "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
> "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
> } ]

Answer (score 4):

Your endpoint `https://<instance_name>/services/data/v53/SurboChat/SaveChatTranscript` in the postman request is incorrect for custom rest resources.
That should be:

```
https://<instance_name>/services/apexrest/SurboChat/SaveChatTranscript
```

---

This is well described in the documentation of the [RestResource Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm)

> The URL mapping is relative to
> https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/

Comment: thank you.. this works :)